# Encoding movie files into h264

Tags: encoding, h.264, cuda

Found some topics about archiving into h264, but those were about the generic questions (does it worth it, which codec to use.)

I want to use h264 (with CUDA (if possible)). So far I only found Avidemux a usable encoder with x264 but it makes an unwatchable video file after the encoding (using the best profile, all setting maxed out), really blurry.

Please write down detailed what to use, where to get it (if its free, doesnt matter), what to set, etc.
Thanks in advance.

(OS: Windows 7 ulti x64, VGA is VP2 capable with CUDA GTX260 XFX)

---

Of course, if there is an **up to date** duplicate, just comment with the link and I'll remove the question ASAP.

Comment: For CUDA I found "Badaboom". Not a bad converter, but its pretty stupid. Its ok only for a movie or something like that not for batch converting (like series). Hope some next version will bring proper support for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Handbrake, it is usually pretty good for H.264.

Comment: What % should I use at quality? Used 100%, got a really good pic but it takes 1.5gb instead of the 250mb source.. >.>